# Float object vertical spacing with "Here definitely" settings using scrbook

Tags: spacing, floats, paragraphs, scrbook, vertical

Vertical gap before float object is too small and after it is too big. For this example I used to set Here definitely positioning, but gaps are similar for every other float placement settings.

I tried:

```
\setlength\intextsep {12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

but with no sucess.
Any idea how to overcome this issue?

[image]

Hope you wanted to see something like this... This is the best MWE I could provide, if it is MWE at all.

```
%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,serbian,BCOR=7.5mm,headings=optiontohead,twoside=false,listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\cfoot*{}
\def\nompreamble{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
aaaaaa & aaaaaa & aaaaaa\tabularnewline
\hline 
aaaaaa & aaaaaa & aaaaaa\tabularnewline
\hline 
aaaaaa & aaaaaa & aaaaaa\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{bla bla bla}
\end{table}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE (minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem. Without it we cant help you.

Comment: @Zarko MWE code added.